# Copy and paste rich text with links but without hidden styles etc in Javascript

Tags: javascript, copy-paste, richtext

I'm building a chrome extension that relies on grabbing selected text from the page and displaying it later.

What I want is to copy a paragraph of text like this:

```
<span class="padding:0px;>Hello this is a link <a href="/somewhere">somewhere</a></span>
```

And to return this:

```
Hello this is a link <a href="/somewhere">somewhere</a>
```

I.e. I want to grab the text, and things like links, LI, UL, Blockquote but not grab hidden styling, etc.

The function I use currently is:

```
function getSelectionText() {
var text = "";
if (window.getSelection) {

  // from here: https://gist.github.com/gleuch/2475825
  // selection range
  var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);

  // plain text of selected range (if you want it w/o html)
  var plaintext = window.getSelection();

  // document fragment with html for selection
  var fragment = range.cloneContents();

  // make new element, insert document fragment, then get innerHTML!
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.appendChild( fragment.cloneNode(true) );

  // your document fragment to a string (w/ html)! (yay!)
  var text = div.innerHTML;
  console.log(text);


} else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") { // think this is for IE?
text = document.selection.createRange().text;
}
return text;
};
```

This grabs the full node fragment of the selection but sometimes grabs surrounding spans, divs, styles etc.

Is there some in between? i.e. not just the raw text and not the full HTML?

Answer (score 0):

If you can enumerate the tags you want removed, use the following function to remove them:

```
function removeTags(tags, html) {
  var els = $(html); // Transform html in a jQuery object
  for (var tag of tags) { // For each tag to be removed
    var el = els.find(tag);
    while (el.length) { // While the tag is found
      el.replaceWith(function() {
        return this.innerHTML; // Remove the tag
      });
      el = els.find(tag); // Find next instance
    }
  }
  return els.html();
}
```

Call it like this:

```
const tags = ["div", "p"]; // List of tags to be removed
var result = removeTags(tags, html);
```

```js
function getHTMLOfSelection() {
  var range;
  if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
    range = document.selection.createRange();
    return range.htmlText;
  }
  if (window.getSelection) {
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    if (selection.rangeCount > 0) {
      range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
      var clonedSelection = range.cloneContents();
      var div = document.createElement('div');
      div.appendChild(clonedSelection);
      return div.outerHTML;
    }
  }
  return '';
}

function removeTags(tags, html) {
  var els = $(html);
  for (var tag of tags) {
    var el = els.find(tag);
    while (el.length) {
      el.replaceWith(function() {
        return this.innerHTML;
      });
      el = els.find(tag);
    }
  }
  return els.html();
}

function process() {
  var tags = ["div", "p"];
  document.getElementById("output1").value = getHTMLOfSelection();
  document.getElementById("output2").value = removeTags(tags, getHTMLOfSelection());
}
```

```css
div,
p {
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><p>Testing...</p>This <div style="color:blue">text to <a href="test">test</a> the</div> selection on.<div style="color:red">Another div</div></div><br>
<button onclick="process()">Get selected HTML</button> HTML:
<br>
<textarea id="output1" rows="3" cols="60"></textarea>
<br> HTML without tags:<br>
<textarea id="output2" rows="3" cols="60"></textarea>
```